# My select command doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, ado.net

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 and I added a new Item as `report.mdf` to my project as database; I created a table `Table1` and I have added one record manually to the `Table1`; but when I try to select  the data I can not do it and get this error:

> invalid attempt to read when no data is present

This is my code:

```
SqlCommand objcomand = new SqlCommand();

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString=@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\EHSAN\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\report\report\App_Data\report.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

objcomand.Connection = con;
objcomand.CommandText = "select * from Table1";

con.Open();

SqlDataReader reader1 = objcomand.ExecuteReader();
string i = reader1.GetValue(1).ToString();

con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to advance the `DataReader` to the next block of data with [`SqlDataReader.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx):

```
string i = null;
// use using for everything that implements IDisposable like a Connection or a DataReader
using(var reader1 = objcomand.ExecuteReader())
{
    // a loop since your query can return multiple records
    while(reader1.Read())
    {
        // if the field actually is the first you have to use GetString(0)
        i = reader1.GetString(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok,I said that I have manually added a field to my table,so the reader.read() should be true!so I didn't use it.am I right?

Comment: @sarahsh - correct, it not only returns true; it also advances the `SqlDataReader` to the first record in it's results.

Comment: yes,realy I didn't know that it is important,so exciting for me!thank you so much.

Comment: @sarahsh: Since your query probably returns multiple records i've used a `while`-loop. You should use a `List<String>` or a `List<CustomType>`(where `CustomType` is a self-made class) and add items to it in the loop. Othwerwise you would always overwrite the last value with the next.